# How to show a message on the last page of pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to show a message according the page where user is. This is what I got so far but something is wrong and I don't know why...

```
    global $wp_query;
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
        $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
        $count_post = wp_count_posts('post');
        $total = (int) $count_post->publish ;
        $total_pages = ceil( $total / $posts_per_page );

if ( $paged == 1){
             echo 'this is page number 1'; // work's fine!
       }
        elseif ( $paged > 1 ) {
            echo 'these are pages bigger than one'; // work's fine!
       }
        elseif ( $paged == $total_pages ) {
            echo 'this is the last page of pagination'; // FAIL!
           }}}
```

Comment: what are the dumped results for $paged / $total / $total_pages for a simple case where you are supposed to be on last page?

Comment: there are no dumped results for `$paged == $total_pages` because it can't determine the last page. However, when I'm on the last page, I see: `these are pages bigger than one`

Comment: try to dump all these 3 vars (and maybe $count_post too) before the line `if ( $paged == 1){`, so that the vars are displayed everytime. Then you can try to see what is happening

Comment: would it be the order of the statements? The final page would satisfy the last two arguments. Maybe try reversing order of the if/elseif statements

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can save time to someone...

Changing the order (and doing minor tweaks) of the statements solved the issue like mentioned by **@alexwc_** on the comment above. Thanks, [@alexwc_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843781/alexwc)!

```
if ( $paged >= $total_pages){
    echo 'this is the last page of pagination'; // work's fine!
} elseif ($paged === 1 ) {
    echo 'this is page number 1'; // work's fine!
} elseif ($paged > 1 ) {
    echo 'these are pages bigger than one'; // work's fine!
                            }
```